# linq-to-entities join 3 tables and group-by statement

Tags: linq, entity-framework, join, linq-to-entities, group-by

Consider the database schema in the picture.

[image]

I need a linq-to-entities statement that will retrieve authors and their respective books grouped by author. For example, I want to display something as follows:

```
authorName8
  bookTitle27
  bookTitle35
  bookTitle62
authorName37
  bookTitle9
  bookTitle51
```

An additional constraint is the oject of grouped items has to be returnable by a method.

Can anybody formulate join and group-by statement (a) ordered by author name, (b) ordered by author name and book title?

Comment: What models did `EF` generate? `Author` and `Book`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention which version of EF you are using, or whether you need to filter the authors by some condition, or filter the books by some condition. A general query that will fetch everything will look like this:

```
List<Author> authorsWithBooks = 
                 context.
                 Authors.
                 Include(a => a.Books). // For EF 4.1
                 /*Include("Books"). instead for previous versions of EF */
                 /*Where(a => !a.IsDeleted). if you want to filter the authors */
                 ToList();
```

If you want to filter the book collections, you will have to write a more elaborate query though.

Comment: : I have a technical difficulty -- perhaps because I apply code-first(?) -- to get your approach to work in my case, but I’m inclined to believe the Include method may be responsible for the grouping trick.

Comment: @Yakimich :: How do you control ordering of author names and book titles?

Comment: To order the authors you add `OrderBy(a => a.Name)` after the `Include`. Ordering the books is more of a challenge, though. Are you using EF 4.1?

Answer (score 0):

var query = (from customer in MyDataContext.Aurthor select author)
                .Including(author=> author.Books);

This will get you all the authors and eager load the books for best performance.